# On a coalgebra structure of simplicial homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Are there any results on the homology group of an abstract simplicial complex with coefficients in a field $k$ being a $k$-coalgebra?

Are there any assumptions and restrictions on the topological or algebraic or combinatorial nature of the complex for this to happen? Or are there any implications on the nature of the complex derived from the coalgebra structure of the homology?

I'm sorry if the question is too vague, but I really don't know how and where to search for such a question.

Thank you.

Comment: I was suggested that it has something to do with the Alexander-Whitney diagonal map. Can anyone please expand this notion in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a more general question which covers my concerns [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415/does-homology-have-a-coproduct).

I'm going to accept this answer in the following days unless there are other.